# How far back can the FAA go in requiring documentation of IFR currency?

Tags: instrument-flight-rules, faa

I did an IPC recently and got to thinking how long I needed to retain the proof of re-up. Let's say that a pilot stays IFR current for 10 years after the hiatus requiring an IPC. For whatever reason, the pilot can document staying current during that period, but has lost the IPC endorsement and so cannot document the the chain of currency was founded legitimately.

It certainly would beg belief that the FAA would pursue an administrative action against a pilot who simply cannot document an endorsement a decade prior, but *would* is not the same as *could*.

How far back can the FAA demand a chain of proof?